# Html not visible in print

Tags: html, web-applications, printing

How to make that text is visible on web page but invisible in print web page. I can not use media queries.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define a print css file.

Have a look at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

You just need to include two different css file (my preferred method):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="css/print.css" />
```

Comment: The edited version works in IE6 onwards as this technique has been used for years - http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html (article from 2000 on it)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text inside an element and give it a class. For example, if the text doesn't already have an element where you can add a class, you can add a span.

```
<span class="printInvisible">This is a text</span>
```

Then, you can define a css for printing (you don't need media queries for this) with:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" href="print.css" />
```

And define your class as not visible in this stylesheet to hide it, like:

```
.prinitInvisible {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.prinitInvisible {
     display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you state that you cannot use media queries you might be able to create a separate stylesheet for printing.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

If you can you use javascript and definitely cannot use the above, you could add a class to all things that should not print (e.g. `class='no_print'`) and when you click the print option use javascript to assign another class to the `no_print` to make them invisible.

For example with jQuery

```
$('.no_print').addClass('hide');
```

or do it with css directly

```
$('.no_print').css('visibility','hidden');
```